# How to return inner join query result

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have some data from 2 databases that i want to return back to the screen
So usually i do something like:

```
foreach($this->seminar->readSubscription() as $value) {
    $this->content .= '<tr>';
    $this->content .= '<td>'.$value->title.'</td>';

    $value->title is then the title from a table.
```

But now i need 2 different id's from 2 different tables so i tried stuff like

```
$value->seminar->id;
```

or something like this:

```
$value->seminar.id;
```

But nothing seems to work any ideas?

This is my query:

```
$result = $this->getDb()->query($query);
    $values = array();
    while(($row = $result->fetchObject()) !== false) {
        $values[] = $row;
    }
    return $values;
```

Comment: Try use print_r($this->seminar->readSubscription()); and see how the object looks like. Pretty basic stuff!

Comment: I cannot print or echo any values my application is build in objects, i fill the objects and eventually return the content. the problem is nog that i dont get any results, the problem is i dont know the correct syntax to get the 2 id's from different tables.

Comment: If you do not get any results: is your query working? witch way are you using to fetch the results?

Comment: Ofcourse if i just do $value->title for example i get the title returned...the problem is i need seminar id and subscription id, both named id

Comment: well if you make your query like "SELECT table1.id as seminar_id, table2.id as subscription_id ... its just like: $value->seminar_id and $value->subscription_id

Comment: Thanks! that was the answer i was looking for!

Comment: Oke great I did not follow you at first hand. Can you please accept my answer? In case future searchers can find the answers for this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case:

You are fetching the results as object not as array. I always fetch an array so my first answer was not clear.

If your query look like this:

```
SELECT a.`name` as name1, a.`otherthing`, d.`name` as name2 
FROM  `ploatjens` AS a
LEFT JOIN  `mapjens` AS d ON a.`dir` = d.`id`
```

note that a.name and d.name have the same alias so I use `as newname` to give them both a unique one.

Then you can access the object like this:

```
//your loop
$name_of_a = $value->name1;
$name_of_b = $value->name2;
$other = $value->otherthing;
//end of your loop
```

When of course using fetch array you can access by using this:

```
//your loop
$name_of_a = $value['name1'];
$name_of_b = $value['name2'];
$other = $value['otherthing'];
//end of your loop
```

Answer (score 1):

In your 'select' query use aliases for your field names.

Reg

Comment: I know that, but what syntax to use in php, i have 2 id's from 2 different tables.

Comment: How do you fetch your db result because usually you get an array not an object. Then it would be $value->seminar['id']; if not an array this should work if it really is an object $value->seminar->id;

Comment: Value->title does return the title of seminar, but like i said i have seminar id and subscription id, i tried the 2 things above nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Still can't you use print_r or var_dump. I do not understand why you use to access the value with $value->seminar->id;. There is no second object. And is the information form 2 tables or form 2 databases. Probably you can just use $value->id or how ever you call the element. I will post an example I often use.

Comment: Once i do $value->id i get the id of the first table id mentioned in the query